# App Center Events take hours to get associated with crashes

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

We are testing the App Center crash reports and event tracking.

We send a few Analytics.TrackEvent(EVENT_NAME, dictionary) and they are quickly shown in the analytics/events page.

We are forcing some crashes using Crashes.GenerateTestCrash() or attempting to divide by zero.

We see the crash fairly quickly. Sometimes it takes a few minutes to show up.

However, the Events associated with the crash, when entering the crash report and clicking in the Events tab, take 6 to 10 hours to appear!

Sometimes they don't show up at all and we get the message "It looks like the App Center Analytics SDK was not installed or enabled at the time of this crash." which is not true, because some crashes got the Events, after a long time, with the same app build.

Is this normal or is it possible we are missing something?

Comment: every AppCenter page has a Chat icon on it that you can use to contact the Engineering team

Comment: yeah I've reached them, they said the delay is normal and it can take up to 24h. I suppose it will work but is something they could improve, I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, there's nothing you can change.